# How do you make a Maytag Bravos XL washer drain?

Tags: repair, appliances

My Maytag Bravos XL washer stops in its spin cycle and won't continue. I unplugged the power and looked in. Lot of un-drained water and clothes. I tried to start it in Rinse Spin cycle but won't. Gives  DRN error code.

How do I simply drain the water out--- not manually of course.

Comment: It would help if you can include what error code it's giving you.

Comment: Does the manual give a button sequence to force a drain? Most do.

Comment: Just checked the manual. -- There are 5 things to check under the Won't Drain section.

Comment: This not automatic but most washers will drain if the drain hose is below the level of the tub. You can try draining that way into a bucket, pan, or something convenient.